# When trying to use company-rust, company cannot find racer even when provided a correct path

Tags: emacs, rust, dot-emacs

I'm having some issues getting company-rust to work the way it should. It loads fine initially, then dies with this error when I attempt to actually use it:

> deferred error : (file-error "Searching for program" "no such file or directory" "racer")

The path is correct and I can [use it in `eshell`](http://puu.sh/m3ryx/c7ebb8facf.png). I'm on most-recent OSX, with the `railwaycat/emacs-mac-port` as emacs.

My [init.el](https://gist.github.com/Az4reus/1fff3487ef8320149eca) is here, and I'm not quite sure of what is causing it, and I'm kind of out of ideas.

Comment: I'm having a somewhat related issue with the rust layer, but I have `(setq-default rust-enable-racer nil)` meaning it shouldn't use racer for auto completion at all and I get the same warning

Answer (score 1):

```
(setq company-racer-executable "path/to/your/racer")
```